# Dbscan density connectivity

Tags: dbscan

Does someone know if the preposition  "not exist a point belonging to a cluster and a point doesn not that are density connected" is correct for dbscan? In basic version is not guaranted that two points that are density connected will belong to the same cluster.It can happen that two point a1 and b1 (not core points) belonging to two different clusters will be connected by a third point that is core but is processed later due to randomly extraction of unvisited points.At this moment the algorithm will create a new cluster for that core point avoiding to add a1 and b1 to it because they are already visited.So is this an error reported in some books or is there an omission in the usual algorithm (Wikipedia version for istance) ?

Comment: I fail to parse your grammar.

Comment: But note that DBSCAN only proceeds with "random" points when there are no unprocessed neighbor points. But there is a corner cases and it is explained in the original paper. Read the papers, not Wikipedia.